# How to capture the MySql error code?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

For example:

```
SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction ROLLING BACK
```

I get this message from a PDOEception thrown inside my code. I would like to intercept the error code (`1213`) and give it specific treatment.

Why?
For example deadlock means I just have to resubmit the query after a microsecond or so. Other errors, means I need to alert developers etc).

Right now I have to code (inside a class inheriting `PDO`):

```
    try{
        $this->lastStatement = $sql;
        $this->lastStatement->execute($params);
    }catch (PDOException $e){
        return $this->error($e);
    }
```

I can not use the `getCode` of `$E` as it seems to not have the total range of errors MySQL has. For example, the following error: `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`
will return `HY000` Which is a very general code. Used on many different error types.

**Should I parse the error message?**

Comment: What about using `$e->getCode()`? Does it return anything meaningfull?

Comment: See answer below about getCode()

Answer (score 2):

```
$e->getCode();
```

It contains the SQLSTATE code, where `40001` means "deadlock".

Comment: Check this error which is lock related and I have to take care of the same way, but it gives the general error this time: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Comment: Yeah, that's more of a problem. I don't know any way of getting the more detailed error codes, besides "reading" the string programatically. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, The only choice I see is parsing the error message itself and extract the four digits error code.

```
$s='SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction';
$p='/\b[0-9]+/';
preg_match($p,$s,$m);
var_dump($m);
```

Answer (score 0):

PDO Statements have a function ->errorInfo() which returns an array of useful info - check $err[2] where $err is the array returned from the above mentioned function.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php